# How do I correct this javascript if i want to deselect checkbox?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a javascript code in regards to customising a group of check box. However the result is not what I am look for. Its almost 90% there.

This is the code I will explain what it does below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>checkboxes</title>
<meta content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" name="GENERATOR">
<meta content="Visual Basic .NET 7.1" name="CODE_LANGUAGE">
<meta content="JavaScript" name="vs_defaultClientScript">
<meta content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5"
name="vs_targetSchema">
<script language="javascript">
function SingleSelect(regex,current)
{
re = new RegExp(regex);

for(i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {

elm = document.forms[0].elements[i];

if (elm.id == 'class') {

elm.checked = false;

}
}

current.checked = true;

 }
/script>
</HEAD>
<body>
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
<table width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td>
<br/>Class 1
<input type="checkbox" id="class" name="cat[]" value="class 1" checked    onclick="SingleSelect('chk',this);" />
<br/>Class 2<input type="checkbox" id="class" name="cat[]" value="class 2" onclick="SingleSelect('chk',this);" />
<br/>Class 3<input type="checkbox" id="class" name="cat[]" value="class 3" onclick="SingleSelect('chk',this);" />
<br/>Class 4<input type="checkbox" id="cat" name="cat[]" value="class 4"  />
<br/>Class 5<input type="checkbox" id="cat" name="cat[]" value="class 5"  />
<br/>Class 6<input type="checkbox" id="cat" name="cat[]" value="class 6"  />
<br/>Class 7<input type="checkbox" id="cat" name="cat[]" value="class 7"  />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

This code consists of 7 check box from class 1 to class 7. Currently, for class 1, class 2 and class 3, It would like to allow user to either choose one only. which is what i want.

For class 4, class 5, class 6 and class 7, it would allow users to choose multiple or single or leave it.

However what i want is:

Of Class 1, Class 2 and Class 3, Users are only allowed to choose 1 or don't choose.

Of Class 4, Class 5, Class 6 and Class 7, I do not mind if users select multiple or single or leave it. But of the 7 choices, Users must at least choose 1 in order to submit or else there should have an error message asking them to choose something.

Can anyone help me to edit the javascript code?? or guide me on how to allow checkbox to be uncheck for Class 1, Class 2 and Class 3 Group of check box.

Thanks very Much in advance

CHeers

Comment: Haven't read through the whole thing, but "/script>" jumps out.

Comment: What you want am not geeting by your question. how to uncheck the checkbox? i.e if check2 is checked check 1 and check 3 should uncheckd

Comment: @KunalVashist sorry for poor structure was doing doing this till 7am before i sleep...so maybe my question is not logically right..but i saw your solution...it works good for my case.

Comment: @Corbin I think this mistake was due to the transferring of coding from Dreamweaver... I accidentally press delete while indenting  every line to make it into the code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This javascript should work for you:

```
<script language="javascript">
// fix form so that only one of the first three is clicked at a time.
// return false if form has no elements clicked.
function validateForm(clickedElement) {
 var myForm = document.forms[0]; // consider document.getElementById("Form1");
 var hasOneChecked = false;
 var clickedFirstThree = (myForm != clickedElement);
 var i;
 for(i = myForm.elements.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
  var elem = myForm.elements[i];
  if(i >= 3 && elem == clickedElement) {
   clickedFirstThree = false;
  }
  if(clickedFirstThree && i < 3) {
   if(elem != clickedElement) {
    elem.checked = false;
   }
  }
  if (elem.checked) {
   hasOneChecked = true;
  }
 }
 return hasOneChecked
}

// validate the form and alert the user if there is a problem
function SingleSelect(e) {
 var isValid = validateForm(e);
 if(!isValid) {
  alert("Please check at least one item.");
 }
 return isValid;
}
</script>
```

But note that you will need to change ALL of your inputs to contain

```
onclick="SingleSelect(this);"
```

With this piece of code out of the way, I think that the other answers here have given you lots of good advice about how you can improve the rest of your page. Some things to consider:

1. Each `id` attribute should be unique
2. A table that contains a single piece of data is pretty useless
3. Formatting your code will make it easier to read
4. Remember to close all of your tags correctly (no missing angle brackets)
5. Consider adding `type="text/javascript"` to your script tag.
6. Consider changing your doctype to xhtml if you want to use self-closing tags like `<br />`

Comment: thanks for the solution...i tried it and it worked...hmm but can i ask something just for learning purposes? In this `function SingleSelect(e)` why is it e? am i right that `onclick="SingleSelect(this);"` is the function that state that if the user uncheck the last checked box the message 'Please check at least one item.' will appear?

Comment: however if i want the message to appear only upon clicking submit, can i put the `onclick="SingleSelect(this);"` into the `<input class="applynextbutton" type="submit" name="applynextbutton" value="PROCEED" />` ?

Comment: @Hubert Yes, is the answer to all of your questions. `SingleSelect()` checks if the form is valid and alerts if it is not. You can add it to the submit button as you said and it will work as well. This is the reason for the line `var clickedFirstThree = (myForm != clickedElement);`, to check if the function is being called from a form element or a checkbox element. And yes, `e` is just short for element.

Comment: i tried adding the `onclick="SingleSelect(this);"` to the button but the alert will still appear before i click on submit to check ( in the situation if I uncheck all the checked box)...is it possible to change the way of alert being trigger by the unchecking of all the check box  to pressing the submit button instead?

Comment: @Hubert try using `onclick="validateForm(this);"` in the checkboxes and `onclick="SingleSelect(this);"` in the form submit.

Comment: Thank You!! You help is really appreciated...at least i learn something new

Answer (score 2):

For class 1,2,3 you can do like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test(e) {

                if (e.checked) {
                    var get = e.id;

                    for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {
                        var getting = document.forms[0].elements[i];
                        getting.checked = false;

                    }
                    e.checked = true;

                    }


            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="Form1" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1"  name="test[]" value="1" onclick="test(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox2"  name="test[]" value="1" onclick="test(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox3"  name="test[]" value="1" onclick="test(this)"/>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This works fine...but if i have a usbmit button is there any javascript that i can use to validate the if there is a selection?

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to use the same ID multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but isn't it easier to split up the different types of input instead.
Then you can have a server-side (client-side, or both) validation that at least one of the options 1-7 is selected.

Use for example radio-buttons for the first three (Class1, Class2 and Class3).
And just use checkboxes for classes 4 to 7.

```
<input type="radio" name="none" value="None" checked>No choice for 1-3<br>
<input type="radio" name="class1" value="class1">Class1<br/>
<input type="radio" name="class2" value="class2">Class2<br/>
<input type="radio" name="class3" value="class3">Class3<br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="class4" value="Class4">Class4<br/>
...
<input type="checkbox" name="class7" value="Class7">Class7<br/>
```

Comment: hi i tried this method...but when inserting the data into database that time it failed terribly...

on going to the next page, i add `$class=$_POST['class']` the name for the radio button was the same...i think i was wrong on that part...but when i select None, the system still insert the value none into the database which was not what i expected...but i think its because of my if else statement not logically right...so i though changing all to checkbox and restricting selection would be best of choice...but most likely i am wrong

Comment: Just an example, but I can't really understand your comment. How your handle your form-input is a different question. You could just name the "no choice for 1-3" to whatever you like, and just don't use that one in your backend-code where you save your data. Hope you figure it out or else, throw a new question about form data => php. Best regards, M